# Creating GNU radio flowgraph for continuous switching between transfer and receive mode

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio

I am having a hackrf-one device which can either transmit or receive signals. I am having a GNU radio flowchart which has a selector block which allows manual switching.

[image]

I am not able to switch it at fast rate manually. I am curious to know that is it possible to control the selector block manually so that the reception and transmission can switch at faster rate so i can receive the signal which i am transmitting.

Comment: The selector block doesn't interact with the HackRF, at all. So, this isn't the right approach.

Comment: You'll want to write a GNU Radio block that directly uses libhackrf to control the hackrf and get samples to/from it. However, more of a programming question than a signal processing question; your original StackOverflow platform was better suited for this kind of question...

Comment: Can you tell if the possibility is there for making it work using rapid switching?

Comment: yes, I wouldn't have recommended doing it?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about implementation of a non-DSP block in a specific platform. I suggest asking directly in gnuradio's mailing list.